# If $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric matrices, then is $A+B$ a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices

Based on the title of the question I edited to be clear:

We have: $A^T=-A$, $B^T=-B$. Then, is $A+B$ a symmetric matrix?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric, i.e., $A^T = -A$ and $B^T = -B$, then the sum is also skew-symmetric as we have

$$(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T=-A-B=-(A+B)$$

and not necessarily a symmetric matrix.